# Como parar um programa em determinado tempo de execução - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Oi, estou tentando rodar um script que encontrei na internet para rodar um programa chamado "Xfoil". O problema é que ele trava algumas vezes, então eu precisaria colocar um timer para fechar o programa em determinado tempo de execução. Como eu faço isso? Sou leigo em Python, se puderem me ajudar eu agradeço. No Final do código está minha tentativa de finalizar o processo "xfoil.exe".

```
#Runs an XFOIL analysis for a given airfoil and flow conditions
import os
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import time

# %% Inputs

airfoil_name = "E423"
alpha_i = 0
alpha_f = 20
alpha_step = 1
Re = 100000
n_iter = 100

# %% XFOIL input file writer 

if os.path.exists("polar_file.txt"):
    os.remove("polar_file.txt")

input_file = open("input_file.in", 'w')
input_file.write("LOAD {0}.dat\n".format(airfoil_name))
input_file.write(airfoil_name + '\n')
input_file.write("PANE\n")
input_file.write("OPER\n")
input_file.write("Visc {0}\n".format(Re))
input_file.write("PACC\n")
input_file.write("polar_file.txt\n\n")
input_file.write("ITER {0}\n".format(n_iter))
input_file.write("ASeq {0} {1} {2}\n".format(alpha_i, alpha_f,
                                             alpha_step))
input_file.write("\n\n")
input_file.write("quit\n")
input_file.close()

start = time.time()
subprocess.call("xfoil.exe < input_file.in", shell=True)
end = time.time() - start
print(end)
if end>3:
    os.system('wmic process where name="xfoil.exe" delete')

polar_data = np.loadtxt("polar_file.txt", skiprows=12)
```

Answer (score -2):

Em Python 3.3+

```
#Runs an XFOIL analysis for a given airfoil and flow conditions
import os
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import time

# %% Inputs

airfoil_name = "E423"
alpha_i = 0
alpha_f = 20
alpha_step = 1
Re = 100000
n_iter = 100

# %% XFOIL input file writer 

if os.path.exists("polar_file.txt"):
    os.remove("polar_file.txt")

input_file = open("input_file.in", 'w')
input_file.write("LOAD {0}.dat\n".format(airfoil_name))
input_file.write(airfoil_name + '\n')
input_file.write("PANE\n")
input_file.write("OPER\n")
input_file.write("Visc {0}\n".format(Re))
input_file.write("PACC\n")
input_file.write("polar_file.txt\n\n")
input_file.write("ITER {0}\n".format(n_iter))
input_file.write("ASeq {0} {1} {2}\n".format(alpha_i, alpha_f,
                                             alpha_step))
input_file.write("\n\n")
input_file.write("quit\n")
input_file.close()

start = time.time()
subprocess.call("xfoil.exe < input_file.in", shell=True, timeout = 1000)
end = time.time() - start
print(end)
if end>3:
    os.system('wmic process where name="xfoil.exe" delete')

polar_data = np.loadtxt("polar_file.txt", skiprows=12)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).